# How did 'entreat', but not 'treat', shift to mean 'to enter into negotiations'?

Tags: etymology, prefixes

> [entreat (v.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=entreat&searchmode=none)
>
> c. 1400, `"to enter into negotiations,"` especially "discuss or arrange peace terms;" also "to treat (someone) in a certain way," from Anglo-French *entretier*, Old French *entraiter* "to treat," from ***en- "make"*** (see [en-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=en-&allowed_in_frame=0) (1)) + *traiter* "to treat" (see [treat](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=treat&allowed_in_frame=0) (v.)). Meaning "to beseech, implore, plead with (someone)" is from early 15c.; meaning "to plead for (someone)" is from mid-15c.
>
> [[OED:]](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/62960?rskey=9ltWzt&result=2&isAdvanced=false)
>   †I. To treat; to handle. Obs. or arch.
>
> ... II. With additional sense of asking, asking *of* somebody or *for* something.

1. Why might've only '**en**treat' shifted to signify `to enter into negotiations`, but not 'treat'?
2. Does the prefix '**en-**' (the only  difference between these two) explain why?

Comment: [*Treat* **does** mean "enter into negotiations."](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/205381?rskey=ntWdVa&result=3&isAdvanced=false#eid) But it's a specialised use only used in the phrase "invitation to treat" in respect of offering goods for sale.

Answer (score 2):

The verb *treat* in the sense of entering into a negotiation with someone toward a particular end was part of the Middle and Early Modern English lexicon:

> …and therefore, I conseille, that ye sende youre messageres, swiche as ben discrete and wise, unto youre adversaries, telling hem on youre behalf, that if they wol [*trete of pees and of accord*](https://books.google.de/books?id=lClYAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA119&lpg=PA119&dq=%22trete+of+pees%22+Chaucer&source=bl&ots=5_ybIq3vVX&sig=k9sdpkm56PfSVXmZ-uS79chbIpk&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQiYyKoaXbAhUuxqYKHaojBH8Q6AEwBnoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22trete%20of%20pees%22%20Chaucer&f=false), that they shape hem, withouten delay or tarying, to come unto us. — Geoffrey Chaucer, “The Tale of Malibee,” *The Canterbury Tales*, 1387–1400.

Besides negotiating for peace, the online [Middle English Dictionary](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=byte&byte=220065862&egdisplay=open&egs=220072497&egs=220105514) shows other complements: one could “trete” between two people as a negotiator, negotiate a truce, a treaty, the provision of a ship, debt resolution, or a marriage. One could also “trete” oneself out of one’s rights. The verb was also used intransitively.

In Lydgate’s retelling of the story of Oedipus and Jocaste, a delegation goes to the queen to urge her to marry:

> For which the lordës all br oñ assent
>   with-Inne the touñ / set a parlament,
>   Shortlye concludyng / if it myght beñ,
>   Prudently [*to trete*](https://archive.org/stream/lydgatessiegeoft00lydgrich#page/34/mode/2up/search/%22trete+with+the+quene%22) with the quene [Jocaste]
>   …
>   To condescende / be way of Mariage,
>   She to be Ioynëd to this manly knyght [Oedipus] — John Lydgate, *Siege of Thebes* 763–769, 1420–22.

Given the difference in status, the delegation is *entreating* the queen to marry rather than negotiating with her.

Shakespeare uses the same *treat of* construction, but with a more general object in the modern sense of ‘to hold diplomatic talks’:

> *Faulconbridge*: And once dispatch'd him in an embassy
>   To Germany, there with the emperor
>  
>   [*To treat*](https://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/views/plays/play_view.php?WorkID=kingjohn&Act=1&Scene=1&Scope=scene) of high affairs touching that time. — *History of King John*, 1,1.

In current usage, *treat* in this sense has almost completely narrowed to a fixed collocation, though with a change of preposition: *treat for peace*. The frequency of the expression, however, [began a steep decline](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=treat+for+peace&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctreat%20for%20peace%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctreat%20for%20peace%3B%2Cc1) in the first decades of the 20th century.

> Soon after its departure the first mission reported back with news that the English king was advancing towards Scotland with his army, forcing William to issue a fresh military summons. With his kingdom made vulnerable by his indecisiveness, William had no real alternative but [*to treat for peace.*](https://books.google.de/books?id=NZq8BQAAQBAJ&pg=PT25&dq=%22treat+for+peace%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpj9O2naXbAhXCXhQKHfGbD4oQ6AEIKzAB) — Richard Oram, *Alexander II: King of Scots 1214-1249*, 2012.

*Treat* as negotiate also remains a part of legal language in England and Wales. In a [compulsory purchase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compulsory_purchase_in_England_and_Wales) — in the US, eminent domain — a Notice to Treat is issued to a property owner to negotiate compensation at fair market value. In contract law, an [Invitation to Treat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invitation_to_treat) — US: invitation to bargain — means to enter into non-binding negotiations.

The *en-* prefix will have had little to do with the divergent histories of *treat* and *entreat*, since words borrowed from Latin, with or with a French intermediary, don’t often preserve the meaning of the prefixes, i.e., no one who enters into an agreement senses the verb and preposition together are a tautology. And it is a rare case where anyone can determine why meanings evolve over time. The narrowing of *treat* is likely because other uses such as treating someone to lunch, treating a topic, or treating an illness began to occupy so much lexical space that there wasn’t much room left for *treat* as negotiate, and it disappeared from common usage.